# Codeiginter mysql storing chinese characters as questions marks

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, utf-8, character-encoding

When I type in chinese characters to store in the database, it becomes ??? question marks instead.

Anyone can help me with this?

My codeigniter config settings for char set is

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8'; 
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

my meta tag is as below as well

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue occur when you have not set the table charset to utf8. Check your table and set its Chartset to utf-8 and collation to utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci (which is best for your language :) ).

This will fix the issue.

Thank you

Comment: yea you are right. I changed the table collation to utf8. works correctly. thanks