# Codeiginter mysql storing chinese data as question mark

Tags: php, mysql

Chinese is display as question mark, when insert data via query. How to insert chinese data. When i save data on double click it's working.

I am using codeigniter with mysql.

```
My database charset is : utf8
My database collection is : utf8_general_ci

My table charset is : utf8
My table collection is : utf8_general_ci

character_set_client : utf8mb4
character_set_connection : utf8mb4
character_set_database : utf8
character_set_filesystem : binary
character_set_results : utf8mb4
character_set_server : latin1
character_set_system : utf8
```

I have already tried utf8_unicode_ci but it doesn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeiginter mysql storing chinese characters as questions marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664982/codeiginter-mysql-storing-chinese-characters-as-questions-marks)

Comment: Yes, but it's not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem you need to set `utf8_unicode_ci` charset to save Chinese character. So just go and ALTER your `charset`.

Comment: can your share screenshot of your table charset

Comment: What about the charset? It is utf8?

Comment: Yes, I have used ALTER TABLE `table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;

Comment: I'm talking about database character set